# How to make mesh partially hidable in blender

Tags: blender

Im not very good at 3D modeling, so hope you can answer my question in a simple way.

Im trying to make a building or its walls have a effect / animation / cute trick, where they can become transparent partially.

Think of Diablo3 in a dungeon, when the character goes behind a wall, then the wall is cut in the middle and hides the top part temporarily.

[image]

The problem is that i want the building to look perfectly intact while in Phase 1.
And the Phase 2 should be activatable from Unity, so if a ray hits the building while trying to see a character behind it, then activate phase 2, and deactivate it again when the character has moved past this part.

thats why im thinking an animation is needed. but what do you guys think?

How would i do this in Blender?

Comment: In blender you can use a mask or boolean modifier to hide part of the mesh, I wouldn't know how to do it in unity. This is more of a unity question as that is where you want to make it happen, even if you have to make the parts in blender. [gamedev](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) might be a better place for this.

Comment: actually the question is more about blender. How does this mask thing you mentioned work? and what does it do exactly?

Comment: The [mask modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/mask.html) will hide vertices in the mesh - ones belonging to specified vertex group. A [boolean modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/booleans.html) will let you use another object to cut part of the mesh away. Expect them to only work in blender - not unity. Maybe a transparent material can be enabled/disabled in unity.

Comment: Just released - [this shader](http://blendbits.blogspot.com.au/2017/02/the-cutaway-shader-free-blender-add-on.html) might interest you. Only had a quick look but it is specific to cycles so may only give you ideas.

Comment: @sambler alpha release, but seems to be in the direction that i wanna go. So thanks, ill hafto wait for it to realease in atleast beta. Dont know enough about shaders to fix any potential bugs i run into.